# Arrange Divs as a letter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/bdqgszv5/1/

Code without jsfiddle:

```
<section id="aussteller" class="row separated">
                <div class="section-header text-center">
                    <h2>Aussteller</h2>
                    <h4>Unsere Aussteller informieren Sie über die neusten Innovationen</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="aussteller">
                        <div class="aussteller-info">
                            <div class="aussteller-photo">
                                <img src="http://allbrochures.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/ricoh-logo.jpg" alt="Ricoh">
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                        <h3>Ricoh</h3>
                        <p>Zeigt uns im RICOH-truck die neusten Drucksysteme</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="aussteller">
                        <div class="aussteller-info">
                            <div class="aussteller-photo">
                                <img src="http://reonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lexmark-logo-18863_640x480.jpg" style="width: 220px; height: 220px" alt="Lexmark">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Lexmark</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="aussteller">
                        <div class="aussteller-info">
                            <div class="aussteller-photo">
                                <img src="http://www.samsung.com/us/images/common/samsung-logo.jpg" style="width: 220px; height: 220px" alt="Samsung">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Samsung</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="aussteller">
                        <div class="aussteller-info">
                            <div class="aussteller-photo">
                                <img src="http://cf.juggle-images.com/matte/white/280x280/papyrus-logo-primary.jpg" style="width: 220px; height: 220px" alt="Papyrus">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Papyrus</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="aussteller">
                        <div class="aussteller-info">
                            <div class="aussteller-photo">
                                <img src="http://seeklogo.com/images/F/Fujitsu-logo-5CECF13A58-seeklogo.com.gif" style="width: 220px; height: 220px" alt="aussteller 5">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Fujitsu</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,  sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="aussteller">
                        <div class="aussteller-info">
                            <div class="aussteller-photo">
                                <img src="http://a1135.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/5f/85/bd/5f85bd7c-f6f9-6544-25fb-f00fd604b21a/mzl.snejseuw.png" style="width: 220px; height: 220px" alt="aussteller 6">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h3>ELO</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Now I would like to reorder it, so that I can get this:

[image]

It should be responsive and never loose the order.
How could I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard. perhaps using certain classes for first and second 6 items, then other items in pairs will have other classes (items should be wrapped in a common div)

Comment: You have to try by yourself first and then come up here if you face any problem while trying!! SO is not for _how to do this_ and ask for complete code!

Comment: I asked for tipps for how to get it started. trainoasis gave one, thanks.

Comment: negative marks? why when user already gave question and ask for tips. SO is for helping and op did not ask for code but way. Plus one as this is rude if we will stop new user to asking question.

Comment: @Amwiom Its not necessary to mention to _give complete code_. The statements like _Now I would like to reorder it, so that I can get this, It should be responsive and never loose the order_ makes anyone to think so! If you have read the question PROPERLY then you wouldn't have said so! and there is no point of not being NICE here! It wasn't harsh either and I couldn't express how I feel with words! That was just a piece of advice!! and I haven't **downvoted** either!! I know this is good question but there wasn't effort to achieve the purpose of the question!

Comment: @Amwiom Its all about perspective, and I agree mine is different. I standby my words!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just familiar with css foundation, but I believe is almost the same setup with 12 as the magical number. Code it as a grid width small 2 columns and leave some empty to match your layout.

EDIT: you can use the empty spaces as small 4 columns, or if you can use a center class if possible. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, the idea helped. Here's the result: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbev6vwx/1/